# Adding Event Handlers in Marketing Cloud Personalisation Component

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning-web-components, personalization, evergage

I am new to personalisation and the web template code makeup. So I am struggling to find a way to register events, especially onclick.

When I write it within the client-side code block, nothing happens. Server side works, but it is instant, and works on the entire page.

I am trying to change the attribute of a radio button to checked within the interaction studio component. It is a carousel.

My main question is, where would one write this code for the component? Client Side? Server Side? The LWC itself?

When I do it within the component, and on renderCallback(), trying to use querySelectorAll(".className"), it returns an empty staticNode.